# Symfony2 forms - Date field type allows wrong dates

Tags: php, mysql, forms, date, symfony

I have a form with a date field as below:

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', 'text', array('required' => false, 'label' => 'name'))
        ->add('phone', 'text', array('required' => false, 'label' => 'phone'))
        ->add('email', 'text', array('required' => false, 'label' => 'email'))

        ->add('nextRevision', 'date', array(
                  'input' => 'datetime', 
                  'widget' => 'single_text', 
                  'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd', 
                  'required' => false, 
                  'label' => 'nextRevision'
        ))
}
```

When the form is rendered in HTML, if I introduce an invalid date and send the form, the error message "This value is not valid." is showed, but if I introduce a date like 20144-03-23, the form is accepted as valid, no error message is showed but the date showed is 0002-12-02, and in the MySQL database, the date is saved as 0000-00-00.

Why is this format accepted if I specified the format when the field was added? Is this a bug of Symfony2 form validators? Is there a way to advice the user of this error without using JavaScript? How could I avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have not added any constraints to this field. Thus Symfony does no sanity checks. One way of adding constraints to this field is as follows:

```
 $builder->add('nextRevision', 'date', array(
    'input' => 'datetime', 
    'widget' => 'single_text', 
    'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd', 
    'required' => false, 
    'label' => 'nextRevision' , 
    'constraints' => array( new Date() )));
```

This will check if the entered date conforms to an actual date. If left blank, the validation will not kick in.

Refer to the documentation here: 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Date.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Debreczeni András. I've used the way you said in your answer, but the behavior is the same. Anyway, I think the method should accept the date, because, in fact is a date.